# Fata Error:Main, Resource Not Found Exception

Tags: android

My Application is crashing with an error "Resource Not Found", I have put all the resources in default folder and cleaned+rebuilt the project several times but error remained same. What actually the resource is missing? What possible error is this. Please help !!
Below is the code of the class which caused the resource error. 
`

```
    package com.example.farhan.chitchat;

/**
 * Created by Farhan on 0028, November 28, 2017.
 */


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;


public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final long SPLASH_TIME_MS = 2000;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable mRunnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        mHandler = new Handler();

        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // check if user is already logged in or not
                if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
                    // if logged in redirect the user to user listing activity
                    UserListingActivity.startActivity(SplashActivity.this);
                } else {
                    // otherwise redirect the user to login activity
                    LoginActivity.startIntent(SplashActivity.this);
                }
                finish();
            }
        };

        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, SPLASH_TIME_MS);
    }

    /*@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, SPLASH_TIME_MS);
    }*/
}
```

`11-29 02:15:24.117 3175-3175/com.example.farhan.chitchat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.farhan.chitchat, PID: 3175
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.farhan.chitchat/com.example.farhan.chitchat.SplashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07005b
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)`

Comment: post code and xml layout of splash activity

Comment: Code of file SplashActivity.java is posted already, but I don't have .xml for this class however project is using some other .xml files. Please note that this is a chatting app with firebase integration

Comment: dude R.layout.activity_splash thats the xml you are using for SplashActivity and the one i meant to see

Answer (score 0):

Try to see what element corresponds to 0x7f07005b in your R file.

Comment: Oh, my R.java file is empty what should I do now?

Comment: Which R file are you opening? it should be in /app/build/generated/source/r/debug/yourpackage/R.java

Comment: Thank you so much,  I was looking into wrong file. I have found and resolved the issue. Thanks Cristian